# I want to display the app name in Traditional Chinese in my Flutter app, but I don't know the name of the `values` directory

Tags: android, flutter, dart

For English, create a directory called `values-en`, and for Japanese, create a directory called `values-jp`.
However, when I create a directory called `values-zh-TW` to set Chinese (traditional), the following error message is output when debugging.

```
/android/app/src/main/res/values-zh-TW: Resource and asset merger: Invalid resource directory name
```

I tried using directory names like `values-zh-tw` and `values-zh-Hant-TW`, but the error message was still output.

How can I make the Flutter app display in Chinese (Traditional) on Android?